# Magento 2 import new products with a CSV file and cron job

Tags: magento2, import, script

How to import products with your image and categories from a .csv? I'm using the script:

[Magento 2 import new and update current products with a CSV file and cron job](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/214079/magento-2-import-new-and-update-current-products-with-a-csv-file-and-cron-job)

But I do not work the images or the categories of the product.
Is there a template I can get? Or is there a guide I can follow to do it?

thx

Comment: which type of product you want to import?

Comment: Hello @RutveeSojitra I want to import simple products

Comment: In product import section you will get sample file for upload

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

For product import you will find download sample file:
see in attach image
[image]

Please put in category filed your product category and before import product put your image at pub/media/import path

Comment: Thanks @RutveeSojitra, but that does not solve my doubt. I have my file with the products, what I want to modify is the import script with a cron task to automate it without having to enter the backend, the script reads the products from a .csv file but only adds them in the home category.