# import question - can you just import SKU, price, qty?

Tags: magento2, import, csv

i want to do an upload on Magento which doesnt involve uploading every column - eg product_type, categories etc

i have all that data in - i just want to update my pricing and quantity, is that possible?

Comment: It is not very clear what yo are asking here. Can you improve your question with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered before. Out of the box, Magento 2 doesn't have an option for updating product data from a CSV. Your only options are to delete all products and do a full reimport or write a script that handles updating product data.

Here's another answer that provides a script for updating only SKU, price and quantity: [Magento 2 import new and update current products with a CSV file and cron job](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/214079/magento-2-import-new-and-update-current-products-with-a-csv-file-and-cron-job)

You most likely don't need to create a cron job though. You could just reuse the script and run in manually.

Comment: yes i can do this but everytime i do a full import it requires a new URL key as its rejects what i currently have!

Comment: even deleting products using csv doesnt fix the url rewrite option - anyway to clear this in SQL?