# Products are not updating programmatically Magento2

Tags: magento2, product, store-view, programmatically

I'm trying to update product details by this code -

```
public function updateProducts(){
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // instance of object manager
            $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
            $product->load(3734);
            $product->setStoreId(1);
            $product->setSku('sku'); // Set your sku here
            $product->setName('name'); // Name of Product
            $product->setStatus(1); // Status on product enabled/ disabled 1/0
            $product->setWeight(10); // weight of product
            $product->setVisibility(4); 
            $product->setPrice(100); // price of product
            $product->setCustomAttribute('case_back','Black');
            $product->setCustomAttribute('case_material','Silver');
            
            $product->save();
        
    }
```

Some of the values are updated like Sku and Price but Name and others are not. I tried to update custom attributes also but it results same. For example - **case_back** updated but **case_material** not.

I found out that fields with **Global** scope are updating but **Store View** scope are not even though I set **storeId** also.

So how can I update all of the details of product?

Comment: Try `$_product->setCustomAttribute("code", 'value');` to update the custom attributes.

Comment: @BhaumikUpadhyay Tried that too. I've edited question please check now.

Comment: Which Magento version you are using?

Comment: Please check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/157533/85907

Comment: @BhaumikUpadhyay Magento 2.3.3

Comment: Are you trying to update the products via csv file?

Comment: @Sathishkumar No. I'm using code mentioned in question

Answer (score 1):

You can use the updateAttribute function to update the existing product attribute easily with storewise also.

Here is the sample Code:

```
$updateAttributes['case_back'] = "Black";
$updateAttributes['case_material'] = "Silver";
$action = objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Action');
$action->updateAttributes([3734], $updateAttributes, $storeId);
```

Comment: How can I update product for whole website with every store

Comment: Get all store ids and loop the action and update the products.