# How i create cron script for import product using csv?

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab, cronjobs

Give me idea for creating cron script for importing product csv file

Comment: Can you please check this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/214079/magento-2-import-new-and-update-current-products-with-a-csv-file-and-cron-job) -

Comment: not a good approach to import products through crons, try through system configuration,

Answer (score 0):

Can you please look into this one - [Blog](https://meetanshi.com/blog/import-product-data-programmatically-in-magento-2/)

Can you please check this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/214079/magento-2-import-new-and-update-current-products-with-a-csv-file-and-cron-job)

To create a cronjob:

app/code/Test/HelloWorld/etc/crontab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job instance="Test\HelloWorld\Cron\Test" method="execute" name="test_helloworld_cron">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

app/code/Test/HelloWorld/Cron/Test.php

```
<?php

namespace Test\HelloWorld\Cron;

class Test
{

    public function execute()
    {

        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/cron.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info(__METHOD__);

        return $this;

    }
}
```